# Работа с локальной БД SQLite и облачным сервисом Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: java, android, база-данных, firebase

Доброго времени суток, ruSO!

Имеется оффлайн приложение, в котором в SQLite БД хранятся ссылки на файлы. При первом запуске приложения данная БД формируется в течение 60 секундного прогресса.

Появилась необходимость заранее подготовить эту БД и при первом запуске приложения передавать ее на устройство пользователя из облака, а дальше в родительский каталог приложения. В качестве облака выбрал `Firebase Storage`. Но в силу малого опыта работы с ней хочу уточнить:

1. Целесообразно вообще реализовывать именно такой вариант ?
2. Какие права доступа необходимо выставить для БД, чтобы любой пользователь приложения мог получить файл с БД, а в будущем автоматически получить обновленную БД ?

**upd01**

В локальной БД хранятся таблицы, в одна из которых случит хранилищем ссылок на файлы, которые пользователь может прочесть.

[ввел в поиск слово -> получил ответы -> выбрал нужный -> прочел содержимое]

Чтобы все это работало offline, я создал таблицу:

[запрос-ru | запрос-en | категория | группа | абсолютная ссылка]

Ищем в первых двух колонках, получаем значения всей строки для нужд.

Comment: Вы тут всех запутали. БД Firebase это не одно и то же, что образ SQLite в виде файла из Firebase Storage. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, переписал заголовок, дописал тело вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Эта схема выглядит очень сложно для столь простой задачи.

Почему бы вам просто не воспользоваться Firebase Database?
Не будет никаких задержек при первом запуске и проблем с обновлениями.

Comment: В моей БД SQLite содержится таблицы, набитые разными колонками. Одна таблица служит для поиска ссылок на файлы приложения, которые потом отображаются пользователю на экране. Приложение должно поддерживать offline режим, поэтому я морочу голову этим файликом *.db, который хочу загружать пользователям из сети при первом запуске из Firebase Cloud Storage.

Comment: Offline прекрасно поддерживается в Firebase Database.

Comment: ок. Как мне переехать* с SQLite на Firebase ?  * - две таблицы с несколькими (~5)  колонками и ~500 строк в каждой.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/, у них уже два типа БД предлагается. Второй (новый, Firestore) как мне кажется, вам лучше подойдет.

Comment: Мы можем с Вами обсудить вопрос в диалоге, если Вы делали что-то подобное ранее ?

Comment: У них есть хороший туториал, что и как. Вот в частности про offline https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline